# Apache restrict access to common files

Tags: apache-2.4

I have a bunch of websites under the same domain, like

```
domain.com
a.domain.com
b.domain.com
c.domain.com
```

All of them use the same resources (css and js) so instead of having them hosted on each site I thought it would be a good idea to just host them in one place and use that in all sites so I created an additional virtual host

```
resources.domain.com
```

That is used just to serve static content, however anyone can access it. Not that it wasn't the case when all the files were hosted on each site but now that it is more centralized I was wondering if there is a way to secure those files in such a way that they will only be served when requested from a site from my domain? Lets say a user goes to `c.domain.com` and it needs `resources.domain.com/css/base.css` and it gets served, however if someone at `anotherdomain.com` tries to include this file in their document they should get a 403 response.

I figured I could add something like this to my `resources.domain.com` virtual host but it didn't work out

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName resources.domain.com

        <Location />
                Order Deny,Allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from *.domain.com
        </Location>

        ...

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off with something like this

```
<Files "*">
Order deny, allow
Deny from all
Allow from 128.252.135.
Allow from .mydomain.com
Allow from host.mydomain.com
```

```
<Files ~ "^example\.(js|php)|robots\.txt$">
  Allow from all
  Satisfy any
</Files>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be very effective :/ Files are still accessible from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .htaccess file for this purpose. If you are not able to redirect it from apache's configuration file. Add below listed lines in top of your .htaccess file.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 1.2.3.4  #your public IP address
```

Comment: What is the difference if I would put this code in the virtual host or an htaccess file?

Comment: you can also get this done from httpd.conf but for that you have to share your apache configuration file. As i have no idea about the changes which you made in your apache configuration file. what is your document root? You are adding virtual host lines under the document root where you want to implement above rules? so i suggested you to use .htaccess.